# Picture bug in a Meteor application with iron:router

Tags: image, meteor, iron-router

I'm having a weird issue in a Meteor application using iron:router.
When I route on a page with a parameter and I route back to the simple page, the picture (`<img/>`) is not showing again.

I will also paste the code below, but if you want to go faster I put it in a github: https://github.com/Erdou/meteor-iron-router-picture-bug

To reproduce :

- Click on the *New* link
- Click on the link newly generated
- Click on the *Back to main* link
- As you can see, **only the remote picture is showing**

The code:

#### client/templates.html

```html
<template name="appBody">
  <a href="{{pathFor 'list'}}">Back to main</a>
  <div>
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="list">
  <div><img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/3/3a/Col_Meteorites.png"/></div>
  <div><img src="Col_Meteorites.png"/></div>
  <a class="js-add" href="#">New</a>
  <ul>
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
      <a href="{{pathFor 'item' _id}}">{{createdAt.toDateString}}</a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="item">
  {{createdAt.toDateString}}
</template>
```

#### app.js

```js
Items = new Mongo.Collection("items");

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'appBody'
});


Router.route('item', {
    path: '/item/:_id',
    data: function () {
        return Items.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'list',
    data: function() {
        return Items.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.list.events({
        'click .js-add': function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            Items.insert({
                createdAt: new Date()
            });
        }
    });
}
```

#### Make a copy of the picture in the public/ folder

```
$ mkdir public
$ curl "http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/3/3a/Col_Meteorites.png" -o Col_Meteorites.png
```

As you can see, the local picture is broken while the remote one is still working:

[image: Firefox screenshot of the bug]

The weird thing is that when you look at the picture tag with Firebug, everything seems normal (Firebug even shows you the picture).

Can somebody tell me how to fix this please?

Comment: How about making it relative - `/Col_Meteorites.png` ?

Comment: I'm hesitating between being happy and hanging myself. Thank you, it works! But why it was working when you land on the page and even after a first routing in a simple page, and then routing back? It's still mysterious.

Comment: No idea, it was first thing that I saw and thought I'll share. If that bothers you, you should probably check network calls and see if requests for image were correct

Comment: As long as it works, it doesn't bother me :) By the way, if you post your solution I think it can help other people (everybody won't read the comments)

Comment: I don't understand why I just got down voted. This is a really clear and SO-oriented question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably some issue with routing non-relative images, you should switch

`<img src="Col_Meteorites.png"/>`

to

`<img src="/Col_Meteorites.png"/>`

so it will always point to root of the site.